# Can't connect to database on server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I cannot connect to my SQL Server database when running app on server.

Everything runs fine when debugging but when I run on the server as ASPNET the user is unable to login.

I created the dataabse in a test project then simply connected to this db. My connection string is

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Temp\Barry\fsr\FSR.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

So this asp app runs on IIS 5 and when deployed the initial select works fine as my gridview that I have a binding to shows data but when I run the program (update the db) I hit the following:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open user default database.
>   Login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'hostxxxxx\ASPNET'.]

I am not creating this database programmatically as mentioned previously, simply connecting to an existing database.

The database is located on my c: - but I have added user ASPNET. How can I add this db to the program as a resource rather than reference a copy on c:?

Answer (score 0):

My first question is this: If you have control of the server, why are you using an attached database. From:

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\Temp\Barry\fsr\FSR.mdf
```

There is no reason to attach if you can control the server. Attach the database to the actual instance in SQL Server, not with the bastardized version you have above. The bastardized version is useful on an ISP that does not give you access to SQL tools. Beyond that, it is more work than it is worth.

The second problem you have is authentication. There are a couple of ways to handle this. The easiest is set up a SQL user to access the database. If every user will have login credentials, you can keep the Windows Authentication method, but you have to turn off anonymous access, so every user GETS authenticated. As long as anon is a choice in IIS, it will default to anon and you will have issues. The third way is to impersonate a user for database access. I guess the fourth is open your database wide open, but I don't suggest destruction of security to make something "work".

Comment: Ok so how do I go about doing this? If I remove that from the con string I cannot see the db? Invalid object name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your database on a server, you need to use a server-based connection string - something like:

```
Data Source=servername\SQLEXPRESS;database=FSR;
Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;
```

Your user needs to have a login on the server, and a user in the appropriate database, in order to connect successfully.

See the [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionStrings.com) web site for a huge list of possible connection strings - and what their settings mean and how you can change those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get into your database and assign the proper privileges to the account that is trying to access the database, which in this case looks like the built-in ASPNET account. Instead of the ASPNET account, you should use the NETWORK SERVICE account. You can change this through IIS.